# leaks tool doesn't report memory leak on os x

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory-leaks

I am trying to learn how to use leaks tool from the command line, here is my code that should produce a leak on `NSString`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] init];

    pid_t pid = getpid();
    NSLog(@"pid: %d", pid);

    string = nil;
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:20];

    return 0;
}
```

I learned that leaks refreshes itself every 10 seconds (not sure if this is true, but I set the interval to 20 seconds).

This should produce leaks because it is not in auto release pool and also I compiled with `-fno-objc-arc` for "safety".

I tried to run leaks `[pid]` multiple times with no leaks reported. What am I doing wrong here?
Also, I am a command line fan and really want to be able to use something similar to valgrind, which doesn't support os x 10.8 very well. It is annoying that I have to put sleep in my code in order to use leaks tool.

Can anyone please shine some lights here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

returns a *shared instance* of an empty string (and multiple calls return the same instance).
The Foundation framework keeps a reference to this shared instance, therefore
 there *is no memory leak*.

The same behaviour can be observed with other immutable classes (`NSArray`, `NSDictionary`).

If you replace your line with

```
NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

then you will see a memory leak.

Comment: I shouldn't have forgotten about the string pool. Your solution works. However, if I get rid of 'string = nil' before the program exits, it doesn't work (which makes sense because string is still holding the ownership). But in practice, it's not possible for me to put nil for all objects that I want to monitor. Any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use ARC there's no leak.
2. The empty string (`[[NSString alloc] init]`) is most definitely a shared/reused instance. The system has to keep a reference to the shared instance, so leaks would (correctly) not report it.

A better test would be to use a custom object. Then you can be sure that there is no magic involved.

```
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
#error This leaks test only works when ARC is off
#endif

@interface Orphan : NSObject @end
@implementation Orphan @end


// in main, create an object without keeping a reference to it:
[Orphan new];
```

Comment: I shouldn't have forgotten about the string pool. Your solution works. However, if I get rid of 'string = nil' before the program exits, it doesn't work (which makes sense because string is still holding the ownership). But in practice, it's not possible for me to put nil for all objects that I want to monitor. Any better solution?

Comment: @bohanl No, not when using the `leaks` tool. You could use `__weak` references in ARC, but this would not work in practice because, well, the references are weak.

Comment: @bohanl There's a better tool to debug that kind of problem, though. You are searching for so called "abandoned memory" (memory for that still a pointer exists, yet the object is still not needed any more). Instruments contains the "Allocations" instrument that can be used to perform "Heap Shot analysis" (now called Generation Analysis). That's a brilliant tool to search for abandoned memory.