# How to understand Retain count

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I used following link for understand the retain count.
 
[retain count in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253787/retain-count-in-iphone)

 As per that question output is :

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"a,b,c,d"];
NSArray  *anArray =[[NSArray alloc]init];
NSLog(@"Retain count: %i", [anArray retainCount]);
anArray=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"Retain count: %i", [anArray retainCount]);
```

OUTPUT

```
Retain count: 2
Retain count: 1
```

When I tried this code in my example :

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"a,b,c,d"];
NSArray  *anArray=[[NSArray alloc]init];
NSLog(@"Retain count: %i", [anArray retainCount]);
anArray=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"Retain count: %i", [anArray retainCount]);
```

Then OUTPUT is

```
Retain count: 51
Retain count: 1
```

I can't understand why the retain count of `NSArray` is 51 and after assigning value in array it becomes 1.

I also read 

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html

http://ranga-iphone-developer.blogspot.in/2011/11/what-is-retain-count-or-reference.html

[iOS about retainCount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190640/ios-about-retaincount) 
and other tutorial. but I can't understand the value of `Retain count: 51`.

Pleas Help me. 
Thank You.

Comment: Why give minus. what is wrong?

Comment: Read the answers to the questions that you linked. They're the answers to your question too.

Comment: @KurtRevis I read that answer but I can't understand 51 it should be 2 or 1.

Comment: The absolute retain count of an object is meaningless. See http://whentouseretaincount.com, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730804/how-many-times-do-i-release-an-allocated-or-retained-object/3730835#3730835 or many similar related answers. - In this particular case, `[[NSArray alloc]init]` *might return* a shared instance (compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/18652557/1187415) so its retain count depends on how many instances have already been created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [WhenToUseRetainCount.com](http://www.whentouseretaincount.com) for an explanation on when and why to use `retainCount`.

The count is 51 due to an implementation detail of empty arrays.   It goes to 1 because you are getting the count of a different object.

If using manual-retain-release, then this pattern is a leak:

```
Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
foo = [someObject retrieveTheFooness];
```

The allocated object is leaked.

Use ARC.